how to write trigger to simulate before update to set foreign key field to null upon violation
I have two databases that synchronize with each other. One database is a full set of data, the other is a limited dataset. This means that the limited database sometimes doesn't have the data the foreign key references to. My goal is to set the foreign key field to NULL if the foreign table doesn't have the related record.
My idea is to use a before insert or update trigger, but apparently this doesn't exist in MS SQL. But there does seem to be an instead of trigger.
Is there a way to write 2 triggers to simulate the desired behavior of NULL-ing a foreign key value? One for insert, one for update?
Imagine the following scenario:
CREATE TABLE B (
    B_Id uniqueidentifier primary key
    );

CREATE TABLE A (
    A_Id uniqueidentifier primary key, 
    FK_B_ID uniqueidentifier FOREIGN KEY fk_B_Id_key REFERENCES B(B_id)
    );

Would be extra appreciated if there is a way to perform the update without mentioning every column as table A has a large amount of columns and I prefer not having to update this trigger with each change made to table A.

Why even keep the foreign key constraint at that point?

The databases are identical in structure. The main database has to keep data integrity of course.

"The databases are identical in structure." - Sure, but why? Just drop the foreign keys from the subset database.

That would require me to have different scripts for the different databases. The main database is held by the main office. Each branch has its own database. The main office has all the data, the branches only have their own data. Every 30 minutes all data is synchronized

"That would require me to have different scripts for the different databases." - Doesn't sound hard? Just a single pre-script to drop all foreign keys for all tables. If the tables are the same, then easy enough, just do all of them. If they vary, then use dynamic SQ to do the work for you.

your example is already 'nullable FK'.where is the issue ?what I have not understood ?Suppose that there was  before insert or update trigger then what would be your table design and what would you write there ?

Why Trigger ? When you can make Nullable foriegn key.
Approach 1
-- Create the Customers table
CREATE TABLE Customers (
  CustomerID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  CustomerName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

-- Create the Orders table with a foreign key that references Customers
CREATE TABLE Orders (
  OrderID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  OrderNumber INT NOT NULL,
  CustomerID INT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID)
);

No need to write extra code ,easy maintainance,performance will be  better than trigger.Also this table will contain either valid FK data or it will be null.You can also create filtered index to optmize query.
Disadvantage : if there are  many Nullable FK then that will be waste of disk space.
Approach 2. Many to many relationship.
Here remove FK CustomerID from Table Orders.Create Another Intersection table
CREATE TABLE Orders (
  OrderID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  OrderNumber INT NOT NULL 
);

CREATE TABLE Customer_Orders (
  OrderID INT not null
  CustomerID INT NOT NULL ,
  FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID),
  FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) REFERENCES Orders(OrderID)
);

This example may be not perfect for many to many relation.
